# Magento2 multiple webservers static directory

Tags: magento2, static-content, hosting

I'm trying to run Magento2 on multiple webserves behind a load balancer. So far I have

- sessions stored in database
- app/etc/env.php shared across webservers
- running the site in production mode

The media directory is mounted on NFS.

I want to understand how **generated static content** fits into this paradigm. At some point I need to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, but it looks like it needs database access to work?

I'm trying to produce a 'build' of the application including the generated files so ideally, there'd be some way to do this without the need for connecting to the database.

Can I generate the static content without database connectivity?

Comment: never use database for sessions

Comment: My question is different. It pertains to the static data managed by `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` (read: not the media directory).

Comment: idea is to share it with NFS or sync in real time

Comment: Please note again, whoever comes across this in the future - this question is absolutely **not a duplicate** media dir != static dir....

Comment: you must use latest magento version 2.2.3 or even 2.3

Comment: @MagenX It has nothing to do w/ 2.2.3 / 2.3. It's a relevant question all the way back do Magento 2.0.

Comment: Looks like I can't "answer" this now that it's been erroneously marked as a dupe... I was able to find what I was after in the [cloud dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/live/sens-data-over.html) and the [deploy model source](https://github.com/thejinxters/magento2-testing/tree/master/app/code/Magento/Deploy)